# map two boolean fields of an IModel to a RadioChoice in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a User object with two boolean fields:

```
//User Bean
public class Users {
  private Boolean showContactData;
  private Boolean showContactDataToContacts;
  // Getters + Setters
}
```

I would like to show that as a RadioChoice in the UI using Apache Wicket.

Snippet from the HTML part:

```
<input type="radio" wicket:id="community_settings"/>
```

Java Form with radio in Wicket

```
public class UserForm extends Form<Users> {
  public UserForm(String id, Users user) { 
    super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel<Users>(user));
    RadioChoice rChoice = new RadioChoice<Long>("community_settings", choices, renderer);
    add(rChoice );
  }
}
```

My issue is now that I of course have no attribute community_settings in the Users Object.
I simply want to map those two boolean values to a radio choice in the UI.

How could I do that in Wicket?

Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: It is Wicket 6.0.0 Beta3 (similar to final version)

Comment: `RadioChoice` extends `SingleSelecChoice` meaning it can only set single field. For example you can have a list of choices and you want to select one of them. See http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/RadioChoice.html. If you want to update several fields, then you  can override `Form.onSubmit()` and deal with it there. Probably there is a better solution.

Comment: The problem is not multiselect or not. The issue is that only one of those boolean values can be true at the same time. You naturally would solve that by using a radio box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a model to map the data:

```
RadioChoice<Long> rChoice = new RadioChoice<Long>("community_settings", new IModel<Long>() {
    public Long getObject() {
        if (user.getShowContactData() && user.getShowContactDataToContacts()) {
            return 1L;
        }
        // ...
    }

    public void setObject(Long choice) {
        if (choice == 1) {
            user.setShowContactData(true);
            user.setShowContactDataToContacts(true);
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void detach() {
    }
}, choices);
```

BTW, personally I would use an `Enum`, so there's no special mapping at all. It seems like you are doing things a bit too "low level" and so the wicket model stuff will feel really cumbersome. Try to use objects instead of primitive types if it's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Christoph. I was able to resolve my issues based on your recommendation. We can't modify the Model so easy as the Model is somehow stable and not part of our current refactoring. You might join us at "Apache OpenMeetings" if you are interested in what we do. We currently refactor from Flash to HTML using Wicket.